# Booting my PC takes a couple of tries

Tags: computer-building

I have just built a new PC. It works, but sometimes when I boot or reboot my system, it shuts down before I even get a video signal, and then it starts up again. This process sometimes repeats itself a couple of times before it finally boots properly.

Some details:

- It reboots by itself, without me needing to press the power button again.
- When the boot fails, I can hear the device becoming silent and the green light turning off for a couple of seconds.
- It's a Gigabyte motherboard.
- There is no pattern whatsoever in when it boots successfully, and when it doesn't.
- It can occur even when I reboot from within my operating system, not just with the hardware button.
- Not once has it occurred that booting failed entirely. The only thing that's going wrong is that it takes multiple tries before booting, but it always does in the end.
- It boots successfully about 50% of the time, and 50% of the time it takes one or more extra attempts.

I've tried replacing the PSU with another one, but the same problem occurs. I've read somewhere else that if it isn't the PSU, it's probably a defective motherboard. All the hardware is new and I can return it under warranty, but I'm looking for a more definitive way of diagnosing the problem first. I do not have another motherboard with the same socket, so I can't just replace it. Could anyone help me with this? In return a picture that could save your life.

Comment: My Gigabyte board does this when I overclock too far. Or when I have certain USB devices connected (recent BIOS update fixed that). Remove all USB devices and run at stock speeds to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: It is indeed a Gigabyte board, but I have not overclocked anything and it happens even when I don't have anything connected via USB (and with the default BIOS settings).

Comment: Could be a motherboard problem. But the behavior is exactly what Gigabyte boards do on a failed boot. They reboot and attempt recovery using default clock speeds and the backup Dual BIOS... could you have a failed BIOS flash?

Comment: I haven't flashed the BIOS at all.

Comment: Maybe the primary BIOS flash chip is defective...that would be a motherboard replacement.

Comment: Oh hey, is your Gigabyte one of those with the LED readout on the board? You'll have to look in your manual but if you read the code off the LED just before it reboots it might inform you. Of course, Gigabyte is probably the only people who can really help you.

Comment: Does it reboot itself before, during, or after POST? Any beep codes from any of these?

Comment: If you aren't getting any post codes, this could be caused by just about anything. Disconnect all but the minimal devices (hard drive, mouse, keyboard, and monitor) to see if it boots normally. If it does, start adding things slowly to see which device is the problem. If it doesn't, run Memtest386 and any hardware diagnostics available from Gigabyte.

Comment: It reboots before POST and it even happens without anything connected.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the wattage of your power supply. If this is a high-end gaming machine you may need to upgrade the power supply to about 600-750 watts.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered it. I bought it with a Corsair VS350 (350 max watt), which is more than enough according to a power supply calculator I used (outervision.com/power-supply-calculator). The one that's inside it now is comparable. The system really shouldn't require that much energy. It uses an Intel Pentium G4400 (Skylake) and no standalone GPU. I have 1 RAM module of 8 GB inside it. The motherboard is Gigabyte GA-H110M-S2H.

Comment: Is the behaviour I described typical of systems that are on the edge of the PSU's capability?

Comment: Hard drives use a lot more power during spin up so yes if the system is on the edge it might fail to boot until the drives are up to speed.